# How to get all combination from two lists?

Tags: python

I want to get something input like:

```
a = ['a', 'b']
b = ['c', 'd']
```

and output like:

```
[{a:c, b:d},{a:d, b:c}, {a:c}, {b:c}, {a:d, b:d}]
```

how to write it in python?
the array length  not always 2

I had resolved this by this code:

```
c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    d = []
    for j in range(len(b)):
        d.append({a[i]:b[j]})
    if len(c) == 0:
        c = d
    else:
        tmp = []
        for k in range(len(c)):
            for l in range(len(d)):
                #print(c[k])
                tmp.append(dict(**c[k], **d[l]))
        c = tmp
```

Comment: what code have you written?

Comment: So, just to be clear, you want to get a list of dictionaries?

Comment: what is the length of the arrays `a` and `b`? is it always 2?

Comment: I'd normally recommend that you use itertools.product, but the output format you are showing makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
a = ['a', 'b']
b = ['c', 'd']

i = dict(zip(a, b))
j = dict(zip(a, b[::-1]))

lst = [i, j]

print(lst)
# [{'a': 'c', 'b': 'd'}, {'a': 'd', 'b': 'c'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some more examples of the input. For this specific one I came up with this. It's a bad solution, so would like to know better.

```
def fun(inp1, inp2):
    lst = []
    for i in range(max(len(inp1), len(inp2))):
        if i == 0:
            dct = {inp1[i]: inp2[i], inp1[i+1]: inp2[i+1]}
            lst.append(dct)
        elif i == 1:
            dct = {inp1[i-1]: inp2[i], inp1[i]: inp2[i-1]}
            lst.append(dct)
    return lst
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = ['a', 'b']
b = ['c', 'd']

print([{x: y} for x in a for y in b])
```

I think this should help.
Output: [{'a': 'c'}, {'a': 'd'}, {'b': 'c'}, {'b': 'd'}]

Comment: This is not matching with the output provided.